# IE: SCRIPT5009 variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Столкнулся с непонятной проблемой: в Интернет Эксплорере не хочет нормально отрабатываться автокомплит, хотя в других браузерах все норм.

Консоль показывает

> SCRIPT5009: 'oStreet' is undefined
>   eval code (39) (1,1)

В ИЕ не получается проскроллить и выбрать улицу в выпадающем списке - выбор возможен только стрелками вниз-вверх.Браузер вообще может зависнуть.

Что это может быть? Почему eval?

> upd: проблема типа здесь => 
>   setTimeout("oStreet.parent().addClass('ok');", 50);

Comment: все очевидно: _'oStreet' is undefined_

Comment: Откуда в 2016м берутся желающие передавать строку в `setTimeout`? Этот способ устарел лет на 10...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oStreet - дожен быть в глобальной области видимости. Присвойте как window.oStreet. Либо передавайте функцию в setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    oStreet.parent().addClass('ok');
}, 50);
```

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, Пётр! сам нашел такое же решение - про использование анонимной функции вместо строки = http://javascript.ru/blog/sweet/zlo-skrytoe-settimeoutsetinterval